# Froala React component throwing "cannot set property 'more_btn' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, froala

I am experimenting with the [React version of the Froala rich text editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/react/)

- see also [`react-froala-wysiwyg`](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg/).

I've created a simple Editor component as follows

```
import { string } from 'prop-types'

// note the docs say do this
// import 'froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js'

// but the advice from froala support is to do this instead
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins.pkgd.min.js'

import 'froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css'
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css'

import FroalaEditor from 'react-froala-wysiwyg'

import { FROALA_KEY } from 'config'

// for Froala options see https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/
const Editor = ({ placeholderText }) => (
  <FroalaEditor
    tag="textarea"
    config={{
      key: FROALA_KEY,
      autofocus: true,
      attribution: false,
      placeholderText
    }}
  />
)
Editor.propTypes = { placeholderText: string }
Editor.defaultProps = { placeholderText: undefined }

export default Editor
```

Loosely based on this code [`codesandbox.io/s/agitated-gauss-9rzbt`](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-gauss-9rzbt?file=/src/index.js).

In both my component, and also in the code sandbox, the Froala bundle throws an error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'more_btn' of undefined`

I've gone through a lot of [their examples](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg/tree/master/demo/src) and can't see why this error should appear, or how to prevent it.

Any idea what I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Froala support team, The fix for this issue will be available in the 4.0.4 release.
In the meantime, You can use the V4.0: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-turing-yzon2?file=/src/index.js.

Comment: alas the bug is also present in 4.0.0 as your link shows.

Comment: Yeah, Just noticed, You could probably consider using 3.2.7

Comment: alas pre v4 does not support tracked changes and commenting. I've been informed by Froala support that the bug will be fixed "by the end of this month". In the meantime I am trying out TinyMCE instead.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Pervaiz, this issue will be fixed in 4.0.4 (according to Froala). In the meantime you can add:

```
indexOf: key => Object.keys(this).indexOf(key),
```

To the toolbarButtons object.

Credits for this fix to JeppeKnockaert in the github issue [here](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/4262#issuecomment-876351627)

Comment: Bug is not fixed in 4.04